# Deploying an Excel add-in made using vsto .net 4.0 in client with .net 2.0

Tags: c#, wcf, excel, vsto

I have developed an excel add-in using Visual studio 2010 with target framework as 4.0 client profile. 
The addin works fine on my machine and now I would like to ship my client's machine.
I am hosting my add in my website so that it can be downloaded from there directly.

The problem I am facing is that, on the client's machine the add-in installs fine but does not load. When I go to the Add in section in "Options" menu, after selecting my COM add-in I find that the load behavior says,

Load Behavior: Not Loaded. A runtime error occurred during the loading of the COM Add-in.

My best guess here is that since, I had developed my add-in using .Net 4.0 client profile all the .Net references I used were being references from the version 4.0, and that at the client end it is trying to find .Net 4.0 assemblies, but is unable to locate them since my client has .Net 2.0 hence it does not load the add-in.

But I want to deploy it on a client with .Net framework 2.0 and above, without installing .Net client profile 4.0.

If any one knows how to figure this thing out, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are out of luck from VS2010, but you should be able to deploy an Excel add-in on a .NET 2.0 machine by using the templates from Visual Studio 2008, where I am pretty certain the option is available, so one option is to back-port your solution into VS2008 and one of its "older" VSTO project types. This is no fun, but should work out.

It depends a bit on what your add-on does, but another consideration is to look into the open source / free [ExcelDNA](http://excel-dna.net/), which provides a nice way to create a bridge between XLLs and .NET, enabling easy calls into .NET dlls.

I haven't used it myself, but [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) may also be something to look into.

Comment: Yes, currently looking into Excel-DNA but, slowly due to lack of documentation.As you said moving the entire development into VS 2008 is a good idea, but I am concerned whether my add-in will work on 2013 or not. But anyways thanks to your answer, I am moving towards some definite conclusions regarding to this topic at hand. I will in a week try to post some concrete conclusions on this matter.

Comment: Good luck - moving back to 2008 and .NET 2.0 isn't a fun alternative (no LINQ, no optional parameters... )

Answer (score 1):

You can't develop a VSTO Excel add-in targeting .Net 2.0 using Visual Studio 2010, as far as I am aware.

If you click on New Project on the Visual Studio 2010 start screen, change the Target Framework dropdown list to `.NET Framework 2.0` and browse to `Office => 2007` or `Office => 2010` you will see 'No items found' for both.

If you create an Office add-in targeting .Net 3.5 or 4.0 (or 4.5 on VS 2012) and try and change the target framework after the fact in the Project Properties window, you get the following error:

[image: Error]

You will need to install the .Net framework 4 on the client computer if you want this to work. Every Windows OS >= XP supports .Net 4 so this shouldn't be too problematic!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I feel it does not allow targeting 2.0 because it does not have the corresponding interop available for .Net 2.0. Also, .Net 4.0 projects allow you to embed your assemblies in the project setup, so I did that to remove the dependency on .net framework 2.0.
 and rest assemblies which I am using from the .Net framework are there in .Net 2.0 also

Comment: Ok, I think your main problem is that your application is an Excel Add-In. You could probably use a Windows Form or a Console Application targeting .Net 2.0 and port most of your code over, and do everything you want to do over Interop which would work fine on 2.0, but your application wouldn't be an Excel add-in, it would sort of sit outside and wouldn't look as neat, but if you can't install 4.0 on the client machine that is what I would do!

Comment: Making a Windows form or console app in .Net 2.0 wont help here as, I want to represent data in Excel and play around with its Object structure like we do with HTML's DOM......

Comment: Hmm you can still do all of that from a Windows Form/Console App through Excel interop, the only difference is you wont have a place on the ribbon, you will have to start the application seperately. The alternative is to write your application in VBA, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee767705.aspx) may help

Comment: Yes, VBA is one solution I know but I dont have the time to learn VBA, plus I have developed a huge fancy ribbon for the clients to use for interaction. So, I will have to stick to what I am doing plus find a solution to this problem.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to deploy a VSTO add-in on a .NET 2.0 machine, I have done it (I had actually to downgrade an add-in I had written for .NET 3.5 to get it to run for a .NET 2.0 client). On the other hand, it may require working with VS2008, and targeting older versions of VSTO - and that is not fun.

Comment: @Mathias Maybe you could answer the question then explaining how?

Comment: Done - btw I would happily remove my down vote if you amended your initial sentence to mention VS2010. I think the correct statement is "with VS2010, you cannot create a VSTO add-in targeting .NET 2.0"

Comment: Also done, in retrospect simply saying that something can't be done was short-sighted, as that is rarely the case in IT!

Comment: ... and done as well ;) And yes, completely agree with the "in IT, it's rarely impossible"...

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure to select the .NET 4.0 Framework in the project's prerequisites. Doing so will allow the users to download/install the .NET Framework you are targeting during the installation of your add-in.

You find this setting in

> project properties -> Build -> Prerequisites

This has several benefits:

- You won't receive customer calls that say "Your add-in constantly crashes", because either they install .NET 4.0 together with your add-in or they will not install the add-in at all.
- Once your add-in is loaded, you are sure that the .NET framework you are targeting is installed on the end-user computer.

Comment: Thats what i am saying, I do not want to install .Net 4.0 on my client machine. I am making sure that all the assembly references that I am using are also available in .Net 2.0 and I am trying to get my add in working on my client machine after building it in my VS 2010 with target framework set as 4.0 since, .Net 2.0 does not support VSTO development.